# Render 3D models using QR Code

Tags: android, qr-code, artoolkit, 3d-model

I want to render 3D model in the camera using QR Code. I have been using android 4.0 platform. My question is -

1. How can I store 3D model in QR code? (Since I have seen generator for url, text, location etc. but no 3D model)
2. Do I have to use any AR tracking algorithm (such as NyARToolkit - ARToolkit android version)? If yes, then how the synchronization will happen?

I'm kinda lost. Please help.

Thanks in advance!

[Here is an example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I6MiJKgtbug)

Comment: "render 3D model in QR code" - what does this mean?  A QR code is an encoding of numeric or textual data.

Answer (score 2):

A QR code can hold a maximum of 23624 bits. If you can fit the data for your 3d models in that size limit, there's nothing else that would need to be done. Just encode the data into a QR code on one end, and decode it back into the binary format on the other. From that point, you would present the data as though it were a 3d file, or generated on the fly.

If you need more space, you could design the app being used to scan the QR code to read the QR code and go fetch the data form somewhere else. That could be as simple as encoding a URL into the QR code, the URL being a file with the 3d model. Or you could have a library of models shipping with the app, and the QR code simply corresponds to one of those.

The demo you link to, for instance, the QR code that is being used to show the car/bus decodes to QRA:3DSCar. The software that is reading it simply knows what to do with that string. It's not actually getting the 3d model data from the QR code.